# PHP - Is there an array equivalent to the str_repeat() function?

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am creating a CSV file attachment in which some fields in the CSV string are empty. For these fields, I have a counter which makes concatenating commas precise:

```
$csvString .= str_repeat(",", $counter);
```

This almost exact same function also works for downloading CSV files in my application, but I am using arrays in place of string concatenation. Is there a shorthand way (one operation) to push repeat (including empty) values to a non-empty-array w/o writing a `for` loop? Something such as:

```
$csvArray[] = array_push_multi('', $counter);
```

This is a curiosity question more than anything. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat yes I suppose so I could do something such as array_fill($array_count, ($array_count + $counter), '');

Comment: I edited to make sure users know array is always non-empty

Comment: What do you mean by "...to a non-array"?  What's a "non-array"?

Comment: Non-empty...was a typo I will fix

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`array_fill()`](https://secure.php.net/array_fill) for this.

```
$csvArray[] = array_fill(0, $counter, '');
```

Comment: The csv array is already non-empty and needs new values pushed

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob: What do you mean?

Comment: Merge then current array with empty-fiiled one.

Comment: @u_mulder Thx for the suggestion, but my question was to do this with one operation. Your approach would need to first fill array B with empty values then merge with current array (A)...this is 2 operations

Comment: `$csvArray = array_merge($csvArray, array_fill(0, $counter, '');` is still one line

Comment: Looks like 2 operations to me :) - array_merge and array_fill

Comment: @u_mulder combining array_merge with array_fill worked for me.  in my case, I needed to build an array with 3 different data sets combined.  Thanks!